# Scipy filter analog vs. digital

Tags: filters, filter-design, scipy, analog

It would be greatly appreciated if the usage of the python package scipy's filter (e.g. butter) analog=True argument could be explained. I don't understand what is meant by this (any signal being processed by scipy in python on a computer is discrete and will always be digital?). I an pretty familiar with DSP but have little knowledge of analog signals.

This seems like a simple question, but I have scoured the docs and online forums and not found anything addressing this directly, apologies if I have missed something!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `butter()` doesn't do any signal processing. It is a routine to ***design*** a filter, either digital or analog. I.e., it computes the filter coefficients.

I use Matlab/Octave where you have basically the same function. The command

```
[b,a] = butter(2,1,'s');
```

designs an ***analog*** (`'s'`) second-order filter with angular cut-off frequency $\omega_c=1$. The coefficients are `b = 1` and `a = [1,sqrt(2),1]`, i.e., the transfer function is

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+\sqrt{2}s+1}$$

Comment: And the `butter` function with the time domain set to some number of seconds, or possibly 'd', will design one in the sampled-time ($z$) domain.

Comment: This answer does not actually *answer* the question. It just explains _what_ `butter` does and how to use it. What about the difference between analog and digital filters in python?